# Armadillo vs for loop vectors multiplications

Tags: stl, linear-algebra, armadillo

I want to compare Armadillo performance when I need to element wise multiply two complex vectors. I wrote simple test which calculates processing time. Multiplication is implemented in two ways: Armadillo elementwise multiplication and simple for loop over std::vector. Here is the test source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace arma;
#include <complex>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;
#define VEC_SIZE 204800
main(int argc, char** argv) {

    const int iterations = 1000;

    cout << "Armadillo version: " << arma_version::as_string() << endl;
    //duration<double> lib_cnt, vec_cnt;
    uint32_t lib_cnt = 0, vec_cnt = 0;

    for (int it = 0; it < iterations; it++) {
        // init input vectors
        std::vector<complex<float>> vf1(VEC_SIZE);
        std::fill(vf1.begin(), vf1.end(), complex<float>(4., 6.));
        std::vector<complex<float>> vf2(VEC_SIZE);
        std::fill(vf2.begin(), vf2.end(), 5.);

        std::vector<complex<float>> vf_res(VEC_SIZE);

        // init arma vectors
        Col<complex<float>> vec1(vf1);
        Col<complex<float>> vec2(vf2);


        // time for loop duration
        auto t0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int vec_idx = 0; vec_idx < VEC_SIZE; vec_idx++) {
            vf_res[vec_idx] = vf1[vec_idx] * vf2[vec_idx];
        }
        auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

        vec_cnt += duration_cast<milliseconds>(t1 - t0).count();

        for (int vec_idx = 0; vec_idx < VEC_SIZE; vec_idx++) {
            complex<float> s = vf_res[vec_idx];
        }


        Col<complex<float>> mul_res(VEC_SIZE);

        // time arma element wise duration
        t0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        mul_res = vec1 % vec2;
        t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        lib_cnt += duration_cast<milliseconds>(t1 - t0).count();

    }
    cout << "for loop time " << vec_cnt << " msec\n";
    cout << "arma time " << lib_cnt << " msec\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Result if following:

```
$ g++ example1.cpp -o example1 -O2 -larmadillo 
$ ./example1
Armadillo version: 9.200.5 (Carpe Noctem)
for loop time 2060 msec
arma time 3049 msec
```

I expected that armadillo can multiply faster then simple for loop. Or I am wrong? Is it expected that for loop multiplies two vectors faster?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the problem, more like an observation. If you restructure your code into two separate loops as:

```
#define VEC_SIZE 204800
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int iterations = 1000;
    cout << "Armadillo version: " << arma_version::as_string() << endl;
    //duration<double> lib_cnt, vec_cnt;
    uint32_t lib_cnt = 0, vec_cnt = 0;

    // init input vectors
   std::vector<complex<float>> vf1(VEC_SIZE);
   std::fill(vf1.begin(), vf1.end(), complex<float>(4., 6.));
   std::vector<complex<float>> vf2(VEC_SIZE);
   std::fill(vf2.begin(), vf2.end(), 5.);
   std::vector<complex<float>> vf_res(VEC_SIZE);

   // init arma vectors
   Col<complex<float>> vec1(vf1);
   Col<complex<float>> vec2(vf2);
   Col<complex<float>> mul_res(VEC_SIZE);
   high_resolution_clock::time_point t0,t1;
   for (int it = 0; it < iterations; it++){
      // time for loop duration
      t0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
      for (int vec_idx = 0; vec_idx < VEC_SIZE; vec_idx++){
          vf_res[vec_idx] = vf1[vec_idx] * vf2[vec_idx];
      }
      t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
      vec_cnt += duration_cast<milliseconds>(t1 - t0).count();
#if 1
      }
      for (int it = 0; it < iterations; it++){
#endif
      // time arma element wise duration
      t0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
      mul_res = vec1 % vec2;
      t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
      lib_cnt += duration_cast<milliseconds>(t1 - t0).count();
    }
    cout << "for loop time " << vec_cnt << " msec\n";
    cout << "arma time " << lib_cnt << " msec\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Then the result goes from

```
Armadillo version: 8.500.1 (Caffeine Raider)
for loop time 169 msec
arma time 244 msec
```

to

```
Armadillo version: 8.500.1 (Caffeine Raider)
for loop time 187 msec
arma time 22 msec
```

which was more like an expected result. However, I can't explain why ...

Compiled with gcc7.3.0 and openBlas on a Core i5 M520, Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: It might be wise to do someting with the results (vf_res and mul_res), eg compare them, to ensure they are not being optimised away.

Comment: Claes, thank you for your reply. I tried your code and noticed that in both cases (one or two loops) I have the same timing. But this timing is such:
    for loop time 2073 msec
    arma time 2060 msec


As I we can see now timing is the same. I noticed that putting vectors initialization away from loop changed performance.

Comment: @dmuir, I added code to use results to be sure they are not optimized away (actually on the posted code you can find for loop with 'complex<float> s = vf_res[vec_idx];'. It didn't affect performance.

Comment: @dmuir and vladimir, you are right, it is definitely something regarding the optimization. When I run your code with -O2 flag i get ~3000/4000, with -O0 ~11000/10000 and -Ofast ~100/1000. B.T.W I don't use the wrapper library -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER.